# Xamarin Android WiFi Direct routing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have been working on some wifi direct communication. It currently works but I am having to rethink how routing will happen. I need to route upload streams (two different file inputs and a string input) to specific paths. The ideas I have had to sort the input streams are

1. add a header (can't find any docs on how to accomplish that and this would be by far the easiest way to handle this situation)
2. create a distinct socket for each input stream

I feel like the different distinct sockets could lead to multiple simultaneous connections. I am not sure if that could cause an issue but it seems like it potentially could.

There must be a cleaner way to handle this. I have not been able to track down any documentation on this and I would really like to hear if someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting my own system. sent everything as a byte[] in the format
[Header length][Header][Body]. This made the data easy to parse into it own areas.